# Como cambiar la posicion del icono requestFocus?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente mi problema es el que se muestra en la imagen adjunta, quisiera mover el icono de `requestFocus` a un lado del `passwordToggle`, pero no he conseguido como hacerlo, alguna sugerencia?

acá el `XML`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel1">

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

y acá como hago el llamado a `requestFocus` en mi clase:

```
if (PassWordSignUp.length()<6) {
    PassWordSignUp.setError("Your password is less than 6 characters!");
    PassWordSignUp.requestFocus();
}
```

he intentado algo como esto:

```
PassWordSignUp.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_LEFT).requestFocus();
```

Pero al usar esto me manda este error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.view.View.requestFocus()' on a null object reference

Entiendo que quiere decir que estoy invocando o llamando un método que no existe.

También he intentado hacerlo desde el `XML` así:

```
<requestFocus/>
```

Alguien podría ayudarme?, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución sería colocar el mensaje de error al `TextInputLayout`:

```
 final TextInputLayout tilPass = findViewById(R.id.tilPass); // hay que agregarle un id al xml.

if (PassWordSignUp.length()<6) {
    tilPass.setError("Your password is less than 6 characters!");
    PassWordSignUp.requestFocus();
}
```